# Regex - Replace a part of string between a word in double quotes and comma

Tags: c#, regex

I wanted to replace a part of string between a text in double quotes and comma using Regex. Suppose I have a string like :

`{Name: {\"before\":'Aj', \"after\":'Ajay'} }`

So I want to extract text between `"before" :` and comma. i.e `Aj` and replace it with `"Aj"`. and same way for `after` text to get `'Ajay` and replace it with `"Ajay"`.

Can anyone please help me on this using Regex?

Answer (score 0):

how about replacing `'` width `"`

```
string yourString = "{Name: {\"before\":'Aj', \"after\":'Ajay'} }";
yourString = yourString.Replace('\'', '"');

//result would be: {Name: {"before":"Aj", "after":"Ajay"} }
```

I don't know much about regex, but I hope this works.

Comment: This could do the work but I was thinking if I could do it in Regex safer side. Thanks :)